# NextJS showing state instead of showing error messages from the server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a register page in my NextJS app, basically a user enters their details, once registration is successful, it clears the form and then displays a success message.

It was all working perfect until i decided to add a success message, now if someone just hits the register button without entering any information it straight up shows the success message instead of showing form errors like it used to.

In my register form component, this is the code that runs when hitting the submit button;

```
const submitForm = async event => {
    event.preventDefault()

    setLoading(true)

    try {
        await register({
            first_name: firstName,
            last_name: lastName,
            email,
            setRegisterErrors,
        })
    } finally {
        setLoading(false)
        setShowRegisterForm(false)
    }
}
```

The bit that i added to remove the register form and show the success message is in the `finally` section which is `setShowRegisterForm(false)`

The `register` function is as follows;

```
const register = async ({ setRegisterErrors, ...props }) => {
    await csrf()

    setRegisterErrors([])

    try {
        await axios.post('/register', props)
        mutate()
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.response.status !== 422) throw error

        setRegisterErrors(error.response.data.errors)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in your code
`if (error.response.status !== 422) throw error`
if any error is caught by that try/catch block and if response status is not equal to 422 it throws error and the setting array of error messages is never executed and it wont set any error messages.
if you want to set any error message
you can do
remove your `if (error.response.status !== 422) throw error` block.
and just `setRegisterErrors(error.response.data.errors)` in catch block.

Comment: have you done form validation?